# How To Search Url with http://www.domainname.com in my jquery datatable?

Tags: jquery, datatables

When I am searching my domain with `http://domain.com` it works great. But incase when I search for `http://www.domain.com` it does'nt works.

```
     function dataTableInitialisation() {
      myOTable = $("#EmployeesTable").dataTable({
          "bProcessing": true,
          "bServerSide": true,
          "sAjaxSource": "/Employees/FetchDetails?Deptid=" + @model.Id + "&thresholdLow=4&threshold=100",
          "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
          "bDestroy": true,
          "aaSorting": [[1, 'desc']],
          "asStripClasses": ['color01', 'color03'],
          "aoColumnDefs": [{
                  "aTargets": [2],
                  "bVisible": false
                  }, {
                  "aTargets": [1],
                  "fnRender": function (oObj) {
                  return "<a href='#showemployees' rel='" + oObj.aData[2] + "'></a>";
                  }
           }]
       });
    }
    });
```

When I search `http://www.` generate 2 ajax request made automatically instead of one. How can I correct this in Jquery Datatable?

Comment: can you show what is happening in `/Employees/FetchDetails` ?

Comment: at first ajax call it search for http:// www.domain.com and returns data.In this case another ajax call is made and return no data.if i entered only http:// www only one ajax call is made ,in case when i search for http:// www. two ajax call is made how is it happen?